# An app to add , delete , and view data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created an app which has in its first Activity (home) one Button, which goes to next Activity.
In the next Activity I have put some add, delete and list all Buttons, but it's not working.

Please help me out with this

While deleting the data I should have a check box to select the data in another Activity.

I am using Android Studio 2.1.3

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnAdd" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List All"
    android:id="@+id/btnGetAll"
    android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnGetAll"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/btnDel"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

public class List_View extends ListActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

```
Button btnAdd,btnGetAll,btnDel;

TextView student_Id;


@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnAdd))
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,StudentDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("student_Id",0);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    else {

        StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo(this);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = repo.getStudentList();
        if (studentList.size() != 0) {
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    student_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.student_Id);
                    String studentId = student_Id.getText().toString();

                    Intent objIndent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StudentDetails.class);
                    objIndent.putExtra("student_Id", Integer.parseInt(studentId));
                    startActivity(objIndent);
                }
            });
           /* ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,studentList, R.layout.activity_view_student_entry, new String[] { "id","name"}, new int[] {R.id.student_Id, R.id.student_name});
            setListAdapter(adapter);*/

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(List_View.this, studentList, R.layout.activity_view__student__entry, new String[]{"id", "name", "email", "age", "place", "phnumber"}, new int[]{R.id.student_Id, R.id.student_name, R.id.student_email, R.id.student_age, R.id.student_place, R.id.student_phnumber});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No student!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    if (view== findViewById(R.id.btnDel))
    {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,Delete.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list__view);


    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnGetAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetAll);
    btnGetAll.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
    btnDel.setOnClickListener(this);
}
}
```

Comment: If you are in initial phase of development then I will say that user recyclerview instead of listview. Here is the link nice implementation in recyclerview. http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html

Comment: Thank you for reply,,,, i need code for add data, and view data then delete in another activity

Comment: If you want to add data in list then you need to write two statements. 1) mListOfData.add(newItem); 2) notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: If you want to view the data then you need to register a click listener on your viewholder. and read the data like this mListOfData.get(position); and store the data is some member/variable. and show that data in full view. somewhat in new activity.

Comment: For deletion depends upon how the workflow of you app. If you are deleting data from other activity and not from the list view then you need to implement some eventing between two activities to ensure that data is deleting from both the activities.

Comment: You can have a look at this video, you will get an idea.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9QRKVbPl7g

Comment: Can i change in my code only which i have sent, in adding new data i am facing problem

Comment: added a answer. Try it and share your experience of that solution.

Comment: thank you, i will edit my code and i will check

Comment: i changed my code but still add and listall buttons are not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

OR

In onItemClick try this.

```
String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```